# How can I deploy my C# Socket Server app into an Azure VM ? Is it really a good idea?

Tags: c#, sockets, azure, virtual-machine

I had an idea, and am trying to upload data from a Netduino to a SQL DB hosted in an Azure VM. After struggling with WCF, I have just written a simple app in C# that processes requests through Sockets (code below) and does the job -works fine on my machine/LAN. Since I still don't know much about

Azure VMs, **how can I expose an IP/port to the outside world in such a way that my client application reaches the server part successfully?** 
Currently I can't make the Azure VM to listen to the outside world. I have created an endpoint (with a name, TCP protocol, same public and private ports and checked 'enable direct server return'. To try it, I shutdown the firewall and tried it, from outside, to no avail.

**Can a listener on that port be considered a secure solution?**

**For the sake of simplicity I thought of Sockets, but is it really a good idea ?** Would you guys do differently and still keep it simple as this ?

```
...
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3211);
server.Bind(localEndPoint);
server.Listen(Int32.MaxValue);
while (true)
{
    Socket clientSocket = server.Accept();
    new ProcessClientRequest(clientSocket);
}
...


public ProcessClientRequest(Socket clientSocket)
{
    m_clientSocket = clientSocket;
    new Thread(ProcessRequest).Start();
}

private void ProcessRequest()
{
    const Int32 c_microsecondsPerSecond = 1000000;
    using (m_clientSocket)
    {
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
        string lastRead;
        if (m_clientSocket.Poll(5 * c_microsecondsPerSecond, SelectMode.SelectRead))
        {
            if (m_clientSocket.Available == 0)
                 return;
            Int32 bytesRead = m_clientSocket.Receive(buffer, m_clientSocket.Available, SocketFlags.None);
            // Return a key to the client.
            lastRead = WriteDataToDB(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", string.Empty));
            m_clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lastRead));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your question _"Is this a good idea"_? Have you thought about security?

Comment: WCF is definitely a better idea. Do not abandon it just because you have some newbie problems. Ask questions, learn and benefit from the mature technology.

Comment: I would suggest that you rephrase your question, besides wanting to know if WCF is a good idea, what is your doubt?

Comment: Hey thanks ! Dzyann, currently I can't make the Azure VM to listen to the outside world. I have created an endpoint (with a name, TCP protocol, same public and private ports and checked 'enable direct server return'. To try it, I shutdown the firewall and tried it, from outside, to no avail.

Comment: Exactly. Can a listener on that port be considered a secure solution ?

Comment: I edited your question adding your comments, not everyone reads them. Hopefully this way you can get help!

Comment: The security of a transmission via socket depends on the protocol used in the transmission and encoding of the message. The socket can transmit and receive messages safe or unsafe, it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your VM's endpoint settings on https://manage.windowsazure.com/? Adding a rule there should allow anyone to connect to `<vm-dns-name>.cloudapp.net:<public-port>`.
That's the DNS name, not the VM name. My Meteor app didn't need the direct server return feature.

A sufficiently hard hashing and encryption layer should be secure enough, provided the customers know your public key's [fingerprint](https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm) because [Certificate Authorities can be compromised](http://it.slashdot.org/story/11/10/28/1954201/four-cas-have-been-compromised-since-june).